# Storing C objects in R

Tags: c, r

In the R Extensions manual, I found information about accessing R objects from C.  In my situation, however, I am working with somebody else's C code which has a specialized data structure (call it Foo).  My goal is to have R functions that:

- initialize a Foo object.  I don't want to have to store one of these in terms of R's lists or matrices.
- update a Foo object.  I don't want to have to recreate the Foo object to do this, but rather modify it in place.  Also, this function might return information about whether the update was successful.
- remove the Foo object from memory.

In other words, I would like to keep around a C object in an R environment, using R functions (backed by C functions) to create it, modify it, and delete it.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)

Comment: I am familiar with Rcpp, but I haven't seen an example that does this sort of thing (where I am not actually passing back an R object, but instead a C++ object).  And wouldn't this require me porting the existing C code to C++?

Comment: Most C compiles pretty much as is in C++. As I understand it Rcpp is two way.

Comment: David is correct, in both posts :)   What you want can be done with either external pointers (Rcpp::XPtr) or, possibly more easily, with Rcpp Modules.

Comment: @Dirk Why don't you write an answer for Christopher to accept. I know absolutely nothing about Rcpp, whereas you, I believe, know a little bit about it!

Comment: It is a non-trivial problem, and I am currently working on another Rcpp piece.  I also prefer 'deeper' discussions on our mailing list.

Comment: I may post a followup question on the Rcpp list.  If something comes of it, I'll post a link to the discussion in as a SO answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As mentioned, the idea is to use an external pointer. This is described in the Writing R Extensions manual. Here's a quick example.

Include the relevant R header

```
#include <Rdefines.h>
```

We'll create an object that can hold a C char * of length at most 15

```
const int N_MAX=15;
```

The external pointer would like a finalizer, to be called when the external pointer is no longer represented by any R object. We play it safe here, checking that the pointer address is valid before freeing (with Free, because we'll allocate with Calloc -- these are C level memory allocation functions that persist across calls in to C, unlike R_alloc) and clearing the pointer to signal that it has already been finalized.

```
static void
_finalizer(SEXP ext)
{
    if (NULL == R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext))
        return;
    Rprintf("finalizing\n");
    char *ptr = (char *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    Free(ptr);
    R_ClearExternalPtr(ext);
}
```

Here's our constructor. It takes some R 'info' that it'll carry around with it (not used later in this example) then allocates some memory for a short string. We construct an external pointer with x and info (the R_NilValue is a 'tag' that by convention we could use to label our object -- mkString("MyCObject") or similar). We associate our finalizer with the external pointer. The PROTECT / UNPROTECT are to safeguard against the garbage collector being triggered by the call to R_RegisterCFinalizerEx. The garbage collector may be called when R allocates memory; it's hard to know when this occurs (we could trace the code flow), so we play it safe and add the external pointer to the PROTECT when we create it.

```
SEXP
create(SEXP info)
{
    char *x = Calloc(N_MAX, char);
    snprintf(x, N_MAX, "my name is joe");
    SEXP ext = PROTECT(R_MakeExternalPtr(x, R_NilValue, info));
    R_RegisterCFinalizerEx(ext, _finalizer, TRUE);
    UNPROTECT(1);

    return ext;
}
```

Here's the getter, just referencing the external pointer address and returning it as an R character(1)

```
SEXP
get(SEXP ext)
{
    return mkString((char *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext));
}
```

and a setter that takes the external pointer and a character(1), copying the C representation of the first element of str into our object. We return a logical(1), but could return anything.

```
SEXP
set(SEXP ext, SEXP str)
{
    char *x = (char *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    snprintf(x, N_MAX, CHAR(STRING_ELT(str, 0)));
    return ScalarLogical(TRUE);
}
```

If this is in a file tmp.c, we compile with

```
R CMD SHLIB tmp.c
```

or integrate this in a package as a file `src/tmp.c` and build the package as normal. To use:

```
> dyn.load("tmp.so")
> x <- .Call("create", list("info could be any R object", 1:5))
> .Call("get", x)
[1] "my name is joe"
> ## reference semantics!
> .Call("set", x, "i am sam i am")
[1] TRUE
> .Call("get", x)
[1] "i am sam i am"
> x <- NULL
> gc()
finalizing
         used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells 339306 18.2     467875   25   407500 21.8
Vcells 202064  1.6     786432    6   380515  3.0
```

Here's a second example with a struct holding an int that is incremented.

```
#include <Rdefines.h>

struct Foo {
    int x;
};

static void
_finalizer(SEXP ext)
{
    struct Foo *ptr = (struct Foo*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    Free(ptr);
}

SEXP
create()
{
    struct Foo *foo = Calloc(1, struct Foo);
    foo->x = 0;
    SEXP ext = PROTECT(R_MakeExternalPtr(foo, R_NilValue, R_NilValue));
    R_RegisterCFinalizerEx(ext, _finalizer, TRUE);
    UNPROTECT(1);

    return ext;
}

SEXP
incr(SEXP ext)
{
    struct Foo *foo = (struct Foo*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    foo->x += 1;
    return ScalarInteger(foo->x);
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, Martin. I still prefer the Rcpp interface but Chris asked for C after all.

Comment: Beautifully answered.  Thank you.

Comment: Follow question:  When the C object is a struct (as opposed to char in your example, which works), I am having trouble doing member access operations.  For example if Foo has int val, then I get a 'memory not mapped' error when I try to mimic the code for get() when x was a char):   
Foo *foo = (Foo *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
int b = foo->val;

Comment: I added a second example; structs should be handled in the same way.

Comment: This is an incredibly valuable Answer. A clear, complete example like this should be part of the "Writing R Extensions" manual.

Comment: It'd be good to add some kind of check before casting R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext) since the user can pass any kind of object in. This seems to work, though I don't know the best way: R_MakeExternalPtr(foo, Rf_install("MyClass"), R_NilValue) and later throw an error if NULL == R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext) || R_ExternalPtrTag(ext) != Rf_install("MyClass")

Comment: @Martin Morgan, your stackoverflow answers are always absolutely amazing. To me, these are probably the most valuable answers one can find on the core R language. You should write a book. I am a fan!