# Is `R_ClearExternalPtr()` needed to finalize an external pointer object in R?

Tags: r

While reading Writing R Extensions, [Section 5.13 External pointers and weak references](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#External-pointers-and-weak-references) we see an example of a finalizer using `R_ClearExternalPtr()` albeit the comment next to it saying *not really needed*:

> (...) The finalizer code is simply
>
> ```
> static void chanFinalizer(SEXP ptr)
> {
> if(!R_ExternalPtrAddr(ptr)) return;
> inRODBCClose(R_ExternalPtrAddr(ptr));
> R_ClearExternalPtr(ptr); /* not really needed */
> }
> ```

In the post [Storing C objects in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032617/storing-c-objects-in-r/7035138#7035138) by @Martin-Morgan he provides two finalizer examples, where he does include a call to `R_ClearExternalPtr()` in the first case but not in the second:

First example:

```
static void
_finalizer(SEXP ext)
{
    if (NULL == R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext))
        return;
    Rprintf("finalizing\n");
    char *ptr = (char *) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    Free(ptr);
    R_ClearExternalPtr(ext);
}
```

Second example:

```
static void
_finalizer(SEXP ext)
{
    struct Foo *ptr = (struct Foo*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(ext);
    Free(ptr);
}
```

Can someone help clarify the comment *not really needed*, and whether I should call `R_ClearExternalPtr()` at the end of the finalizer.